# Order by String with spaces in between

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My Table column "business" looks like this:

```
Michael Kors
Baltimore Michael Kors
Charlotte Michael Kors
Michael Texas
Kors Dallas
Michael Kors
```

I have to apply order by on this column on String 'Michael Kors', so the sorted result should be something like this:

```
Michael Kors
Michael Kors
Baltimore Michael Kors
Charlotte Michael Kors
Kors Dallas
Michael Texas
```

if String contains substring Michael Kors it should be on top in alphabetical order. So in the example above, 2 rows with exact match is on top and after that Baltimore and Charlotte is 3rd and 4th in alphabetical order. Not worried about other strings which does not contain the exact word Michael Kors

I tried using [Substring_Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) but looks like it doesn't works well with substring with spaces. All help appreciated.

Comment: By which rule is one string ordered after another?

Comment: @trincot Updated my Question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple levels of ordering:

```
order by 
  locate('Michael Kors', business)=1 desc, 
  locate('Michael Kors', business)>0 desc, 
  business
```

The first one sorts the exact matches to top, next level sort the rest of the matching rows and the third sorts all the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You could list Boolean expressions in your `order by` clause, and apply a descending order so that records for which this expression is true, will be ordered before those that yield false. Then specify an alphabetical order at the end to determine the order when all other expressions give no distinction for two records:

```
select   * 
from     mytable
order by (business = 'Michael Kors') desc,
         (business like '%Michael Kors%') desc,
         (business like '%Kors%') desc,
         (business like '%Michael%') desc,
         business
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
order by FIELD(business, 'Michael Kors’)
```

Comment: Thanks @Nipun Sampath your solution worked too, I'm evaluating the fastest one out of all suggested here since i have to run this on 10 million of data.

Comment: Happy to help :)